# Adding New Node to an Existing Mongo Replica with Authentication

Tags: mongodb

I've an existing replica set using simple authentication configured and I want to add a new node to the replica.
I now use the following flow to do so:

1. Start the new node as a standalone with authentication enabled and the same keyfile as all other nodes
2. create an admin user locally (with the exact same credentials as the nodes in the replica have)
3. Stop the node
4. Start it again with the replica settings
5. Add it to the replica

But this feels awkward -  having to recreate the user(s) for each node, is there no other way? to just specify the keyfile and connect the new node to the replica?

Thanks